# Plotting exponential function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm relatively new to Python.
I'm trying to plot exponential term value ranging between 0 and 100.
There is no error indicated with the code but the Plot has no legend(line).
Kindly help me.
Thank you.

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range (0,101):
    m = math.exp(i)
    print("For i = ",i)
    print("(e^i) = ",m)
plt.plot(i,m,'b--',linewidth=3)
plt.ylabel('e^i')
plt.xlabel('i')
plt.show()
```

Comment: While the answer below solves your problem, I would also recommend using NumPy. First `import numpy as np` and then directly define the input mesh and perform exponential operation without using for loops: `x = np.arange(101); 
y = np.exp(x)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your code in this way:

```
import math 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
l = list(range (0,101))
m_l = []
for i in l:
    m = math.exp(i)
    print("For i = ",i)
    print("(e^i) = ",m)
    m_l.append(m)
plt.plot(l,m_l,'b--',linewidth=3)
plt.ylabel('e^i')
plt.xlabel('i')
plt.legend(['m_l'])
plt.show()
```

With your code, you were plotting just the last values of `i` and `m`

Comment: You are welcome :) Please consider to accept the answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work